# WP―button to start media library

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a wordpress plugin and I would like to enable the user to use images from the media library. For example: the »Choose Image« button in the »header« section of Theme configuration does exactly what I am looking for.

Is there any wordpress method I can call to generate such a button?

Greetings philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you try to accomplish is not clear,
using all the images is one thing and give them an option to use wordpress uploader is one thing.

give them the last option is not recommended because they can abuse your system without control.

to see all the images you can use this function, return an array :

```
function get_all_images(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' =>'image',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $images = array();
    foreach ( $query->posts as $image) {
        $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
    }
    return $images;
}
```

Comment: What I would like to have is button on the settings page of my plugin. Clicking it should open the media library and enable the user to select an image from there. If you have a theme that has »custom header« enabled and navigate to this settings page, then you can find such a button on that page. I would like to create a button with the same functionality.

Comment: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/how-to-integrate-the-wordpress-media-uploader-in-theme-and-plugin-options/

Comment: that's a good one! Edit your answer with the link, I wonna accept it ;)